# Add multiple points to google map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

Hi i am running a Directory for web links and at the moment a user can add one Location to the map. I would like to see it become in a way that a user can a multiple locations so if the company have 10 Offices in 10 different locations they will be able to add those 10 to there listings page so visitors can see where they are based. I have taken the google map code from my page so i can share how it works. But there is a map on the Home Page that shows all listings, a Map on the Category page that shows all the Listings for the Cat Pages and also a Map on the Web Link Page. So the page where you add web links that has the google map needs to correspond with the other maps so all locations shows.

This Part is where a user writes there address.

```
/*** GOOGLE MAP ***/
if(isset($GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['google']) && $GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['google'] == 1){ ?>

<div class="form-row row-fluid customfield">
<label class="control-label span3"><?php echo $CORE->_e(array('add','37')); ?> <span     class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="field_wrapper span9">

<div class="row-fluid">
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $CORE->_e(array('add','54')); ?>"  onchange="getMapLocation(this.value);" name="custom[map_location]" id="form_map_location" class="span10" tabindex="14" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map_location',true); } ?>">
 <button class="btn btn-warnings" type="button"  tabindex="15" onclick="getMapLocation(jQuery('#form_map_location').val());"><?php echo $CORE->_e(array('button','11')); ?></button></div>

</div>
</div>
```

The Location Box where the user places there address would need to be multiplied so properly be a good idea to have it so it loads a new box once one has been filled in...

The Google map part:

```
<div id="showmapbox" <?php if(get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-country',true) == ""){ ?   >style="display:none"<?php } ?>>
<div id="wlt_map_location" style="height:300px;width:100%;"></div>
<p class="wlt_map_text">
<span class="label"> <?php echo $CORE->_e(array('add','46')); ?> </span>
<?php echo $CORE->_e(array('add','47')); ?>: <span id="wlt_dcountry" class="label label-info"><?php if(isset($_GET['eid']) && get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-country',true) != ""){ echo get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-country',true); }else{ echo '<i class="icon-remove">  </i>'; } ?></span> 
<?php echo $CORE->_e(array('add','48')); ?>: <span id="wlt_dstate" class="label label-info"><?php if(isset($_GET['eid']) && get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-state',true) != ""){ echo get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-state',true); }else{ echo '<i class="icon-remove"> </i>'; } ?></span> 
<?php echo $CORE->_e(array('add','49')); ?>: <span id="wlt_dcity" class="label label-info"><?php if(isset($_GET['eid']) && get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-city',true) != ""){ echo get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-city',true); }else{ echo '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'; } ?></span>
</p>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="map-long" name="custom[map-log]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-log',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-lat" name="custom[map-lat]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-lat',true).'"'; } ?>> 
<input type="hidden" id="map-country" name="custom[map-country]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-country',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-address1" name="custom[map-address1]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-address1',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-address2" name="custom[map-address2]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-address2',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-address3" name="custom[map-address3]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-address3',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-zip" name="custom[map-zip]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-zip',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-state" name="custom[map-state]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-state',true).'"'; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" id="map-city" name="custom[map-city]" <?php if(isset($_GET['eid'])){ echo 'value="'.get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map-city',true).'"'; } ?>>
```

Then Just at the Bottom of Page under the Submit Button we have some more code for google maps but for some reason can not place on here so i have provided a link for a .txt file with the script. [Bottom Snippit](http://www.directweb.co.uk/snip/bottom-snip.txt) this is the script to see the google map script [full Script](http://www.directweb.co.uk/snip/full-snip.txt). I am using Wordpress and Premium Press as well that's how im getting the google map. I have asked around looking if there's any ideas how i can do what i'm aiming for.

Thank you
All the Best
Robert

Answer (score -1):

php code to add multi location on google map (multi projections of location) applied in wordpress CMS

[display_map address1="Eldora, IA" 
address2="Albany, NY" address3="Shreveport, LA" address4="Kingshill, VI" address5="Falfurrias, LA" address6="Baxley, GA" address7="Avon Park, FL" address8="Carthage, NC" zoom=3]